# intersectsBox returns true when expecting false

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I was following the explanation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/3D_collision_detection/Bounding_volume_collision_detection_with_THREE.js) to check on intersection of bounding boxes. So I wrote the code:

```
  const testBoxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 3, 3);
  const testBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
  testBox = new THREE.Mesh(testBoxGeometry, testBoxMaterial);
  testBox.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
  testBoundingBox = new THREE.Box3(
    testBox.geometry.boundingBox.min,
    testBox.geometry.boundingBox.max
  );
  testBox.position.set(5, 0, 5);
  scene.add(testBox);

  const cameraBoxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 3, 3);
  const cameraBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
  cameraBox = new THREE.Mesh(cameraBoxGeometry, cameraBoxMaterial);
  cameraBox.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
  cameraBoundingBox = new THREE.Box3(
    cameraBox.geometry.boundingBox.min,
    cameraBox.geometry.boundingBox.max
  );
  scene.add(cameraBox);
```

And in my animate function

```
  if (testBoundingBox.intersectsBox(cameraBoundingBox)) {
    console.log(`intersection`);
  }
```

As you can see in this screenshot the two green boxes do not intersect and yet it's logged they are... Someone who might know what I might be doing wrong or push me in a direction of debugging this?

[image: Screenshot of intersection constantly logging.]

**EDIT**

as Hectate mentioned, I should add setFromObject(), this fixes my initial problem. However, now I’ve got a new problem, because the first square I use represents my camera. I want to make an environment and check if the player (the camera which simulates first person) is colliding with any object in the area. I do this by making an Object3D() and adding the camera and a square. I will make the square invisible but use it for the bounds to detect collision.

Because I translate (I use translate for performance) the player Object3D, my original position stays the same and the intersection can only OR constantly happen OR never happen… Any idea on how to work around this one?

The code I’m using to navigate my player Object3D:

checking if key is pressed

```
switch (e.key) {
case `z`:
  moveForward = true;
  break;
case `s`:
  moveBackward = true;
  break;
case `q`:
  moveLeft = true;
  break;
case `d`:
  moveRight = true;
  break;
}
```

in my animate function:

```
if (moveForward) player.translateZ(- .05);
if (moveBackward) player.translateZ(.05);
if (moveLeft) player.translateX(- .05);
if (moveRight) player.translateX(.05);
```

**EDIT 2**

This is my full script.js:

```
import sets from './data/sets';

import ColladaLoader from 'three-collada-loader';

import BufferLoader from './modules/sound/BufferLoader';
import SpawnObject from './modules/render/SpawnObject';
import Controls from './modules/util/Controls';

import io from 'socket.io-client';
import {isEmpty} from 'lodash';

const OrbitControls = require(`./modules/util/OrbitControls`)(THREE);
const DeviceOrientationControls = require(`./modules/util/DeviceOrientationControls`);

// const PointerLockControls = require(`./modules/util/PointerLockControls`);

let scene, camera, renderer, VRcontrols, element, cameraBox, testBox, cameraBoundingBox, testBoundingBox;
let audioCtx, bufferLoader;
let socket, controlData;

let player, playerMesh;

let mobile;

let moveForward = false, moveBackward = false, moveLeft = false, moveRight = false;

let camX = 0;
const camY = 0;
let camZ = 2;

let mousedown = false;

const camSpeed = .1;

const notes = [];
let devices = [];
const collidableMeshList = [];

const mobilecheck = () => {
  mobile = false;
  (function(a) {if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) mobile = true;})(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);
  return mobile;
};

const init = () => {

  mobilecheck();

  socket = io(`/`);

  socket.on(`init`, handleWSInit);
  socket.on(`dataTransfer`, handleWSData);

  window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

  if (!mobile) {
    document.addEventListener(`keydown`, useArrowDown);
    document.addEventListener(`keyup`, useArrowUp);
    document.addEventListener(`mousedown`, () => mousedown = true);
    document.addEventListener(`mouseup`, () => mousedown = false);
    document.addEventListener(`mousemove`, e => {
      if (mousedown) {
        const rotateAngle = Math.PI / 4;
        player.rotateY(rotateAngle * e.movementX * .1);
      }
    });
  }

};

const handleWSInit = users => {
  const {id: socketId} = socket;

  users = users.map(u => {
    if (u.socketId === socketId) u.isMe = true;
    return u;
  });

  devices = users;

  if (window.location.href.indexOf(`controls`) > - 1) {
    const controls = new Controls(socket, devices);
    console.log(controls);
    return;
  }

  document.querySelector(`main`).classList.remove(`controls`);

  loadAudio();

};

const loadAudio = () => {
  audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(audioCtx);

  bufferLoader.load(sets.drums)
    .then(data => spawnObject(data));


  initEnvironment();
};

const handleWSData = data => {
  if (data !== undefined || data !== null || isEmpty(data)) controlData = data;

  devices = devices.map(u => {
    u.yo = false;
    return u;
  });

};

const spawnObject = data => {

  for (let i = 0;i < 5;i ++) {
    const bol = new SpawnObject(`object.dae`, audioCtx, data[0], scene, true);
    notes.push(bol);
    collidableMeshList.push((notes[0].scene.children[2]));

  }
};

const initEnvironment = () => {
  console.log(notes);
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    1, 1000
  );

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  element = renderer.domElement;
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  //PLAYER
  player = new THREE.Object3D();

  const testBoxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 3, 3);
  const testBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
  testBox = new THREE.Mesh(testBoxGeometry, testBoxMaterial);
  testBox.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
  const testBoxHelper = new THREE.BoxHelper(testBox, 0x0000ff);
  testBoundingBox = new THREE.Box3(
    testBox.geometry.boundingBox.min,
    testBox.geometry.boundingBox.max
  );
  testBox.position.set(0, 0, 3);
  testBoundingBox.setFromObject(testBox);
  scene.add(testBox);
  scene.add(testBoxHelper);
  const cameraBoxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 3, 3);
  const cameraBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
  cameraBox = new THREE.Mesh(cameraBoxGeometry, cameraBoxMaterial);
  cameraBox.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
  const cameraBoxHelper = new THREE.BoxHelper(cameraBox, 0x0000ff);
  cameraBoundingBox = new THREE.Box3(
    cameraBox.geometry.boundingBox.min,
    cameraBox.geometry.boundingBox.max
  );
  player.add(cameraBoxHelper);
  player.add(cameraBox);
  player.add(camera);
  player.velocity = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
  scene.add(player);
  playerMesh = player.children[0];


  camera.position.set(0, 0, 2); // first-player view
  player.position.set(0, 0, 0);
  player.rotation.y = - Math.PI / 2.0;

  VRcontrols = mobile ? new DeviceOrientationControls(camera) : new OrbitControls(camera);

  //LIGHTS
  const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
  light.position.set(0, 0, 9);
  light.castShadow = true;
  light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
  light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
  scene.add(light);

  //FLOOR
  const matFloor = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
  const geoFloor = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2000, 1, 2000);
  const mshFloor = new THREE.Mesh(geoFloor, matFloor);

  matFloor.color.set(0x212E39);
  mshFloor.receiveShadow = true;
  mshFloor.position.set(0, - 1, 0);

  scene.add(mshFloor);


  const loader = new ColladaLoader();

  loader.load(`../assets/environment.dae`, collada => {
    collada.scene.traverse(child => {
      child.castShadow = true;
      child.receiveShadow = true;
    });
    scene.add(collada.scene);
    animate();
  });

};

const moveCamera = () => {
  // TODO: find movementX (0= no movement, 1-... = movement)
  //dan -> player.rotateY(rotateAngle * e.movementX * .1);
  const movementX = VRcontrols.object.rotation._y;
  const rotateAngle = Math.PI / 4;
  console.log(VRcontrols.deviceOrientation);

  //player.rotateY(rotateAngle * movementX * .1);
  // notes.forEach(i => {
  //   i.audioCtx.listener.positionX.value = camX + window.innerWidth / 2;
  //   i.audioCtx.listener.positionZ.value = camZ + 300;
  //   i.audioCtx.listener.positionY.value = camY + window.innerHeight / 2;
  // });
  //
  switch (controlData) {
  case `up`:
    camZ -= camSpeed;
    break;
  case `down`:
    camZ += camSpeed;
    break;
  case `left`:
    camX -= camSpeed;
    break;
  case `right`:
    camX += camSpeed;
    break;
  }

  camera.position.set(camX, camY, camZ);
  VRcontrols.update();
};

//CODE BENEATH NEEDS TO BE LESS DIRTY.

const useArrowDown = e => {
  switch (e.key) {
  case `z`:
    moveForward = true;
    break;
  case `s`:
    moveBackward = true;
    break;
  case `q`:
    moveLeft = true;
    break;
  case `d`:
    moveRight = true;
    break;
  }
};

const useArrowUp = e => {
  switch (e.key) {
  case `z`:
    moveForward = false;
    break;
  case `s`:
    moveBackward = false;
    break;
  case `q`:
    moveLeft = false;
    break;
  case `d`:
    moveRight = false;
    break;
  }
};


const animate = () => {

  if (mobile) {
    moveCamera();
  }

  if (moveForward) player.position.z -= .05;
  if (moveBackward) player.position.z += .05;
  if (moveLeft) player.position.x -= .05;
  if (moveRight) player.position.x += .05;

  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

  renderer.gammaInput = true;
  renderer.gammaOutput = true;

  renderer.setClearColor(0xdddddd, 1);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  if (testBoundingBox.intersectsBox(cameraBoundingBox)) {
    console.log(`intersection`);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

};


init();
```

Comment: In response to your edit; it looks like `Object3D.translateX` (etc) transforms it within object space which might be the issue - I think you noticed this. Have you tried doing `Object3D.position.x += 0.5;` instead?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, it's still triggering the collision even after not colliding anymore... Perhaps behind the scenes it also translates giving the same effect? Is there any chance I can visualize the bounding box? That might help me understand why this is happening. I found this gif from the example https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/11799/rotating_knot.gif but it's not implemented in the example and thus not in the source code...

Comment: You could try a BoxHelper: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=helper#Reference/Extras.Helpers/BoxHelper

Comment: Oh lord I've definitely not taken enough breaks between starting this project and now. I've seen that helper but didn't read it thoroughly enough. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll keep you posted if I fix my issue, thanks so far!

Comment: I can't explain why yet, but this already shows that there's definitely something wrong... - the blue outlines are the 2 boxes' helpers. https://puu.sh/sU570/2cbe5856bc.png **EDIT** @Hectate https://puu.sh/sU5bk/265acc9eac.png Oh wow, I zoomed out and saw that the box was gigantic. I read something about the collision not being detected when A spawns in B.

Comment: can you share more of the code? I'm curious how each object is being created.

Comment: I understand why the box is so big. I made an Object3D() to add my camera and the box in it for the collision detection which I call "player", my camera will be the size of the bounding box, of course. Now I should just find how I can specify the size I wish my camera to be (I hope I can, else I'm in big trouble...), and then this should be totally resolved.

Comment: Haha. Yeah I suppose if you hadn't put the first-person camera in it that would make it a bit large. Good to hear!

Comment: Do you think I'd be able to fix it with the setViewOffset()? https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=camer#Reference/Cameras/PerspectiveCamera

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130907/discussion-between-hectate-and-kevin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you linked included the following note:

> Note: The boundingBox property takes the Geometry itself as reference, and not the Mesh. So any transformations such as scale, position, etc. applied to the Mesh will be ignored while computing the calculating box.

Following along with that, I used the `setFromObject()` to set the position of the testBoundingBox and it did/didn't trigger the intersection as expected. Here's the interesting code, as well as a jsfiddle showing the behavior. Change the boxes position and rerun to see the interections trigger, of course.

https://jsfiddle.net/87wg5z27/122/

```
  const testBoxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 3, 3);
  const testBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
  testBox = new THREE.Mesh(testBoxGeometry, testBoxMaterial);
  testBox.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
  testBoundingBox = new THREE.Box3(
    testBox.geometry.boundingBox.min,
    testBox.geometry.boundingBox.max
  );
  testBox.position.set(5, 0, 5);
  testBoundingBox.setFromObject(testBox); //I added this line
  scene.add(testBox);

  const cameraBoxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 3, 3);
  const cameraBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
  cameraBox = new THREE.Mesh(cameraBoxGeometry, cameraBoxMaterial);
  cameraBox.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
  cameraBoundingBox = new THREE.Box3(
    cameraBox.geometry.boundingBox.min,
    cameraBox.geometry.boundingBox.max
  );
  scene.add(cameraBox);
```

Comment: Ahhh crap, I read that part but just kept on reading first and was like "Yeah I'll add that code later". Idd, now it works, thanks for the quick and clear reply. Let me update my question because this actually STILL blocks what I'm trying to do....